# Tracking Form element input via Mixpanel through Google tag manager

Tags: input, form-submit, tracking, google-tag-manager, mixpanel

In my GTM container, I set a Mixpanel code to track the Form Element.

> < input class="addtocart_button" vaule="add to cart" type="submit">

But always cannot get any **add to cart** data in Mixpanel, GTM preview is OK.

GTM setting procedure is bellow:

1. building tag -> custom HTML -> Configure Tag:

> ```
> <script>
>   // track an event named "Add to cart"
> mixpanel.track("Add to cart");
> </script>
> ```

-> Fire On: Form

2. Editing Trigger -> event: Form Submission -> Configure Trigger: Check Validation -> Enable When: CSS-addtocart_button equals "add to cart" -> Fire On: Form Element equals input

Could somebody give a good suggestion?

Comment: Can you please post screenshots of your tag and trigger?

Comment: @nyuen here is the album: http://imgur.com/a/2Jsrx

Comment: Have you taken a look at the Mixpanel support pages? https://blog.mixpanel.com/2015/03/27/community-tip-implementing-mixpanel-via-google-tag-manager/

Answer (score 1):

After depressing a few days and no log in, I find the track is WORKing today.

It shows a little bit of datas with add to cart from june 17th to yesterday, but I just really don't know why there are no datas into the dashboard as that day I'm publishing.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Form trigger, then all rules in this trigger should be for `<form>` HTML element and not for  `<input>` or `<button>`.

If you want to track interactions with  `<input>` or `<button>` you should use Click trigger.